# Issue with a network disk context to access images outside Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9, catalina

I'm working on windows, with Tomcat 9.0 / Java 8
One of my servlet will create and manage quite a lot of images.
So we decided to store those on a network disk.

On my Windows server I mounted the resource on P:/

To access images outside Tomcat, I set the context in the **host** of server.xml.
To be sure that it was working fine, I first tried in local like this :

```
<Context docBase="C:/IMG/" path="/RepIMG" />
```

Then if I try to access : **http://localhost/RepIMG/test.jpg**
The image is displayed.

But if I change my context to :

```
<Context docBase="P:/IMG/" path="/RepIMG" />
```

Tomcat will not start at all with this error :
***Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: L'ensemble de ressources principal [P:] est invalide***

=> The main ressource  [P:] is not valid

If I try to access directly P:/IMG/test.jpg with Chrome it works fine.
I checked the permissions on the folder and everything seems to be ok.

Since it's working when I access a local disk I assume the issue is the fact that I try to access a mounted disk.

Is there something to specify or some way to troubleshoot this?
To know exactly what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're running Tomcat as a service (e.g. not through your IDE or Command Line). This way it will run in a different context, likely as a different user. That context/user account doesn't have your local user's drive mapping - only the local disks are the same for all accounts.

Comment: Thanks,
This seems to be the issue.
I tried to start Tomcat with my session but it didn't solve the issue.

I also tried to set the server.xml with the UNC path but to no avail :

<Context docBase="//Srvdata13/scan2dp$/"      path="/RepS2dp" />

.               .
and just in case :
<Context docBase="\\\\Srvdata13\\scan2dp$\\"      path="/RepS2dp" />

Comment: well, those network paths will likely require authentication... Not sure if the service user that tomcat uses is allowed to access them. (Note: I can't help you on windows networking specifics, just point out the most probably cause)

Comment: Ok, I'll continue digging, thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Tomcat 9.0 by default runs as `LocalService` (check in Procrun/Tomcat Monitor), which presents guest credentials on the network. You might want to change it to `NetworkService`, which uses the machine's credentials on the network.